# Can I compress 8 streams of FullHD 30fps video by using hardware encoder NVEN in nVidia GPU?

Tags: video, encoding, gpu, h.264, nvidia

We can use hardware H264 encoder - ([NVENC](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk)):

> API enables software developers to access the high-performance H.264
>   hardware video encoder introduced in Kepler-class NVIDIA GPUs ([See
>   list of supported NVIDIA Quadro, Tesla and GRID GPUs below](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk#gpulist)).
>
> NVENC hardware is designed to support up to 8x real-time HD video
>   encoding (1080p@30fps).  This means the hardware can encode up to 240
>   frames per second of 1920x1080 progressive video.

I can compress FullHD video in 240fps, or 30fps but 8x faster then real-time, but can I compress 8 streams of FullHD 30fps video by using hardware encoder NVENC (30fps x 8 streams = 240fps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can!

As you can see, we are able to compress at least 10 tream(contexts) with a total value of FPS slightly less than for 1 stream(context): [image]

And we can compress 30 fps x FullHD (1920x1080) by using NVENC(hardware codec on Kepler):

- 4 streams with HQ (High Quality)
- 8 streams with HP (high perfomance)

[image]

Taken from:

http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3379-High-Performance-GPU-Video-Encoding.pdf